# Application and libraries "boxing"

Tags: linux, sandbox

I'm running Ubuntu, and found a library that I'd like to run. The problem is that this library is only compatible with RedHat and Suse.

I'm looking for a way to run a Python application using this library in some kind of "box" with RedHat/Suse libraries/structure, but who would run faster (than virtualbox) because of just running CLI, and why not with the host's kernel. It would start automatically, run the application and close after that.

I think I have seen an application like this before, but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called *container*, notable examples are [lxc](http://linuxcontainers.org) and [docker](http://www.docker.io/) (later is build atop of the former and more user friendly)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for, docker is the name I forgot.